# Version compatability issue between Selenium2Library and Extendedselenium2library

Tags: robotframework

I tried to upgrade selenium2library to verision 3.0.0 using

> " **C:>pip install robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0**"

but I got this error.

> "**robotframework-extendedselenium2library 0.9.2 has requirement robotframework-selenium2library=1.8.0, but you'll have robotframework-selenium2library 3.0.0 which is incompatible.**"

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Help you out in what?

Comment: The error message seems clear to me how to proceed. So, can you please elaborate on what it is you want to achieve?